# how to stop wrapped components being spaced

Tags: css, reactjs

I've just created a new react app and I've created my own `Button` component. I'm trying to display loads of these in a row(s).

in my `App.css` I have

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: start;
```

When I shrink my browser the wrapped components appear half way down the screen. How do I make it appear directly underneath?

FYI, there's no css layout on the `Button`.

Comment: I think `align-items: flex-start;` may solve your problem.

Comment: If you haven't set `align-items` it defaults to `stretch` which may cause your problem

Comment: Can you please create a basic example to demonstrate the issue you are experiencing and what you are expecting? It’s not clear what CSS your button components and wrapping components have in their entirety which could be affecting the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 solution...

In my `App.cs` I had

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Removing that sorted the problem. I guess I just need to have an outer div set to full height with an inner div that isn't.